# MathJax/jsMath alternatives?

Tags: mathjax, mathml, jqmath

**Update from 2021:** *just use MathJax; you shouldn't be supporting old versions of IE any more.*

I want to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) to display MathML equations, but its performance in IE is unacceptably slow (yes, I read about using EmulateIE7, this is also unacceptable as it would break other areas of the site).

I don't need to support user-generated equations, and most of my data is already in XML form, so doing an XSL transform to HTML seems like the most compatible solution.

Ideally, the HTML would be similar/exactly the same as that which comes from MathJax. Displaying an image in place of the whole equation is a poor solution, as is requiring IE users to install MathPlayer.

Answer (score 10):

[jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) should be a lot faster, and doesn't use any images or require MathPlayer (though it uses MathPlayer when available).

To use jqmath, you will need to convert your XML equations to a simplified TeX-like syntax, if you don't have them in that form already.

Please let me (us) know if this solves your problem.

Comment: The best thing with jqmath is its ability to directly use unicode chars, for data entry its the best easiest in human readable format to fix any formula issue/change later stage,  where as TEX and MathJax and Katex lacks this

Answer (score 7):

There is a new math typesetting JS library from [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) called **[Katex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/)**.

It is quite fast in comparison, but doesn't include the very advanced stuff of mathjax.

Here is a comparison image :

`|                  Katex               |              Mathjax               |`
[image: comparison Katex vs MathJax]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/katex-comparison.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

MathQuill is also a great tool. However, the hard part is that you must enclose your math equations in `<span>`s and write tons of JavaScript afterwards.
For more reference, see [here](https://mathquill.com/). To load MathQuill, simply add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.min.css"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```